# When local variables are "calculated"?

Tags: performance, local-variables

Does elisp calculate values of local variables at declaration or when calling them?

Say i want to find out what headlines in buffer are lvl2, and do stuff to them:

```el
(defun map-org-heads ()
  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline) 'headline 'do-stuff))
```

Would this:

```el
(defun do-stuff (element)
  (let ((lvl (org-element-property :level element)))
    (if (eq lvl 2)
        (call-func-to-do-stuff))))
```

Have a better performance than this:

```el
(defun do-stuff (element)
  (let ((begin (org-element-property :begin element))
        (end (org-element-property :end element))
        (lvl (org-element-property :level element))
        (title (org-element-property :title element)))
    (if (eq lvl 2)
        (........... do stuff))))
```

I have quite a big org-file with lots of headlines, so every bit of performance matters.

Comment: This question is a little unclear; please clarify it.  You can also test the performance of two different functions by [profiling you code](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html) to see which one is faster.

Comment: The question is unclear, in part because you don't show enough in the two contrasting examples. In the second example you don't show any use of the other local variables, and we can't guess what the correspondence is, if any, between `(...... do stuff)` and `(call-func-to-do-stuff)`.

Comment: Are you asking whether elisp has lazy evaluation? It doesn't.

Comment: `org-element-property` is a two-liner that relies upon either `get-text-property` or `plist-get` depending upon whether ELEMENT is a `stringp`.  Neither of these would consume time with a standard `org-mode`.  It is the combing through of large `org-mode` files and examining that information for multiple headings that causes a noticeable time consumption.  I personally like to search backward for headings (that interest me) from the bottom of the file to the top because point is at the beginning of a heading at each stop (assuming `re-search-backward` is being used).

Comment: Here is a link to a measure-time macro in case you want to wrap it around something that interests you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622296/emacs-timing-execution-of-function-calls-in-emacs-lisp

Answer (score 1):

From the elisp manual for `let`:

> This special form sets up local bindings for a certain set of variables, as specified by BINDINGS, and **then** evaluates all of the FORMS in textual order.
>   ...
>   All of the VALUE-FORMs in BINDINGS are evaluated in the order they appear and *before* binding any of the symbols to them.

Which means that any computations required to define the local variables are done first, then the results are bound to the symbols, and finally the body is evaluated.

Here's a simple(-minded) example:

```
(defun return-tmp ()
  tmp)

(setq tmp 1)

(defun test-let ()
  (let ((tmp1 (return-tmp))) ;; create tmp1, give it the value of tmp
    (setq tmp 2)             ;; change the value of tmp
    tmp1))                   ;; return the value stored in tmp1


tmp          ;; => 1, the initial value of tmp
(test-let)   ;; => 1, the value of tmp when tmp1 was defined
tmp          ;; => 2, the value of tmp when test-let returned
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does elisp calculate values of local variables at declaration or when
>   calling them?

At declaration, thus the value is computed even if you don't use the variable at all.

> Would this: ... Have a better performance than this: ...

Yes, since the former sometimes avoids unnecessary computation. However, don't worry about performance when you are not sure it is worth. If it is slow, you will know. In this case, `org-element-property` is very fast so you probably won't notice the performance difference between these two.